# Incorrect font measures

Tags: cocoa, fonts, nstextfield

On a NSTextField I'm setting a custom font with a size of 140. The text is set to @"28". But as you can clearly see on the image, the text field has plenty of space on top. This only happens with certain type of fonts, not all of them. My question is what information from the font could be affecting the textfield that ends up cropping the text ? (Ascender, Cap Height ?). And if so, can I modify the font file to fix it ?

[image]

Comment: I have seen this too and not only with large text. For example in IB, for a simple label, switch from Lucida Grande (the default on ML) to Helvetica Neue. The position of the text changes by seveal pixels (but it almost gets fixed when you set it to single line mode).

Answer (score 2):

The baseline will vary between fonts.  In addition, there are other metrics that vary.  You can work around this problem with NSAttributedString.  You could try varying the NSBaselineOffsetAttribute and from within a paragraph setMinimumLineHeight and setMaximumLineHeight.  The following is an example.  Make sure to create two textField labels and connect their outlets.

```
self.Label1.stringValue = @"Test Text";
//
// baseline is different for each font!
//
//self.Label2.stringValue = @"Test Text";

NSFont *otherFont = [NSFont fontWithName:@"MarkerFelt-Thin" size:40.0f];
NSNumber *baseline = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat: 5.0f];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paraStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
[paraStyle setParagraphSpacingBefore:20.0f];
[paraStyle setMinimumLineHeight:30.0f];
[paraStyle setMaximumLineHeight:50.0f];

NSDictionary *otherFDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: paraStyle, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                            otherFont, NSFontAttributeName, baseline, NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName, nil];

NSMutableAttributedString *otherText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Test Text" attributes:otherFDict];

self.Label2.attributedStringValue = otherText;
```